# ImportError: No module named twilio.rest error

Tags: python-3.x, twilio

### **ImportError: No module named twilio.rest**

Hi, for some reason I'm getting an ImportError: No module named twilio.rest.  Despite the fact that I have installed twilio with brew and pip3.

---

Here is my code:

```
from twilio.rest import Client 
 
account_sid = '[ACCOUNT_SID]' 
auth_token = '[AuthToken]' 
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token) 
 
message = client.messages.create( 
                              from_='[twilio phone number]',  
                              body='Hiii!',      
                              to='[other phone number]' 
                          ) 
 
print(message.sid)
```

*Thanks in advance for any help!*

Comment: Your import statement is fine meaning it's not installed. Either the pip you used is not the one for the python version you are using or something went wrong when you installed it.

Comment: I'm using pip3 and I have installed it with pip3

Comment: I believe you, but Python apparently does not believe you. Are you running it in Python3 and does pip3 link to the same version of Python as the Python3 command does?

Comment: how do I check that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/dealing-with-multiple-python-versions-and-pip

Comment: Thanks!  It worked!